# ionic 2 error:Unable to find “tslint” command: null

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

i'm new in this website,i'm using ionic 2, when i create new project and run npm run build i get this error, i tried to delete all files and install again but without successful.

```
    npm run build

> ionic-hello-world@ build C:\Users\John\deve\myEventApp
> ionic-app-scripts build --rollup ./config/rollup.config.js

[20:39:57]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.30
[20:39:57]  build prod started ...
[20:39:57]  clean started ...
[20:39:57]  clean finished in 6 ms
[20:39:57]  copy started ...
[20:39:57]  ngc started ...
[20:39:57]  lint started ...
[20:39:57]  lint failed:  Unable to find "tslint" command: null
[20:39:57]  Error: Unable to find "tslint" command: null
    at C:\Users\Adir\deve\myEventApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\lint.js:38:20
    at runTsLint (C:\Users\Adir\deve\myEventApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\lint.js:35:12)
    at C:\Users\Adir\deve\myEventApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\lint.js:22:13
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
[20:39:58]  copy finished in 33 ms
[20:39:58]  ngc failed:  Unable to find Angular Compiler "ngc" command: null. Please ensure @angular/compiler-cli has been installed with NPM.
[20:39:58]  Error: Unable to find Angular Compiler "ngc" command: null. Please ensure @angular/compiler-cli has been installed with NPM.
    at C:\Users\Adir\deve\myEventApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\ngc.js:40:20
    at runNgc (C:\Users\Adir\deve\myEventApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\ngc.js:34:12)
    at C:\Users\Adir\deve\myEventApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\ngc.js:18:16
Error running ionic app script "build": Error: Unable to find Angular Compiler "ngc" command: null. Please ensure @angular/compiler-cli has been installed with NPM.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build --rollup ./config/rollup.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ build script 'ionic-app-scripts build --rollup ./config/rollup.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts build --rollup ./config/rollup.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Adir\deve\myEventApp\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\Adir\deve\myEventApp>
```

i just update my npm to 3.10.8 and my node.js to 6.8.0
i really don't know what the reason for it.